# phonegap file selector plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I need to upload a file to server can be image/text/video etc.

I am using cloud based phonegap build service to build my project.

I would like to know if there is a plugin to select file on an android phone    similar to  in web.

I do know that FileTransfer plugin is used to upload the file.

Comment: The [plugin repository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, [CordovaFile](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) is the one you need, but if you want a specific type, [ImagePicker](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker) plugin for Images, and vor videos you can use [CordovaCamera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

I hope that helps, good luck

Answer (score -1):

I just use [imagePicker plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker) and it works fine for me. It's used like this:

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            alert('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    }
);
```